# Environment named parse-server-test-dev is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, parse-platform

I've created MongoDB using ObjectRocket

[image]

But now when I am trying to add database URI to my aws environment config all works good but when try to change `SERVER_URL` it want me do it:

[image]

I am trying to put this value to `SERVER_URL`:

http://parse-server-test-dev.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/parse

and when I do eb open just to test my Parse Server nothing happened by that link.

Maybe I need to run npm somewhere to make it work.